# Auth dialog improvements (who's logged in, etc)

Tags: feature-request, api-v2

The auth dialog (client side) could do with a bit of improvement.

Specifically, showing the currently logged in user, and a link saying "not you?". Facebook does this and allows you log in as someone else. It's also reassuring to know that it knows who you are.

Also the buttons seem a bit disconnected on the right of the description/etc. On the server side flow they are below the text/line.

Also there is a fair bit of whitespace on the left of the dialog (below screenshot shows a window which resizes to fit the content, it works perfectly on all other pages)

[image]

Comment: That particular "floating approve/reject buttons" style bug has been fixed.  I'll think on the others, "not you?" is tricky because stackexchange.com doesn't necessarily have the display name a user is most familiar with (and a user can have an arbitrary number of names across the network).

Comment: @Kevin, I thought that a while ago the network was updated so that users only have one profile, which was pushed between sites? There used to be a button called "copy profile from stack overflow", which has now disappeared?

Comment: No, profile's are still distinct.  You can't clear associations anymore, that was removed as part of consolidation credentials.  Copy profile should still be visible.